# Getting Real Bad Performance from CAShapeLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, cocoa-touch, graphics

I have a graphic that is stored in a large file and is broken down into a lot of `mutablePaths` like following:

```
mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 123.70,49.23);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 124.57,54.05,124.06,58.98,123.43,63.80);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 123.09,66.42,122.70,69.03,122.43,71.66);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 121.64,81.02,121.35,83.58,120.92,86.11);
CGPathCloseSubpath(mutablePath);
CGPathAddPath(outlineMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);
CGPathRelease(mutablePath);
```

I consolidate all of the paths into 4-5 paths using `CGPathAddPath`, then add each one to a `CAShapeLayer`. I attach the `CAShapeLayers` to a view like following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_graphic.shapeLayers count]; i++)
{
    [self.layer addSublayer:[_graphic.shapeLayers objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

The graphic is being drawn correctly, however, when I go to pull up a modal view on the same screen where the graphic is, the modal view stutters pretty badly when appearing on the screen. Also noticed it takes quite a bit of time for the shape to draw, and in general just seems to weigh down the screen when I try to leave it and go to a different navigational controller. In running a time profile, I notice that most of the time being spent is in `CALayer layoutSublayers` and `CALayer drawInContext`.

The graphic does have a lot of paths, but is not so complex that I think `iOS` should have this much trouble drawing it. When I was drawing these paths manually in drawRect, I wasn't getting this effect. Plus, I was told by an expert that drawing the graphic in this style would be better for performance. This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting `shouldRasterize` property to `YES` on either all the `CAShapeLayers` or `self.layer`.